# How to avoid xml-rpc timeout?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-rpc

In my app (write in c# .net 4.5) i use xml - rpc to transfer messeage.
Somethimes i get WebException from .net.

I try to extract the callstack and the stuck occur at:

```
cookcomputing.xmlrpc.xmlrpc.xmlrpcclient.Invoke()
```

I think it occur maybe because i overload on the connection.

But there is solution to avoid this timeout exception?